# Why am I receiving the error: "sudo: update_prebinding: command not found" on the command line?

Tags: command-line, osx

One of my applications won't open so I'm trying the first thing to do on this website:
http://www.cnet.com/news/tutorial-what-to-do-when-a-mac-os-x-application-will-not-launch/

But I am getting an error for this command that I enter. Why?

```
sudo update_prebinding -root / -force
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving that error because the program "update_prebinding" is not in your PATH, possibly because it is not installed on your system.

Comment: , possibly because it [has been obsolete for about a decade](https://discussions.apple.com/message/677117#677117)

Answer (score 0):

well that answers the exact question so is in line with stackexchange rules but is singularly unhelpful at getting the OP to be able to solve their problem